# Проблемы с t-test scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

[image: Задание]

Есть такое задание. Нужно в python посчитать t-test по уже известным данным (оценка коэффициента и стандартное отклонение).
Есть функция в библиотеке scipy, которая позволяет это сделать, но нужно иметь ряд данных.
Говорю про эту функцию:

```py
scipy.stats.ttest_1samp
```

Она не позволяет внести в неё данные, которые даются в задачу. Других подходящих функций найти не могу.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в этой задаче сделать t-test в python. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция ttest_1samp тут не при делах, она используется только для сравнения средних значений выборок.

Значимость коэффициентов регрессии определяется по известным формулам, см. например https://economy-web.org/?p=292.

После того, как модель построена, уровень значимости q выбран, количество степеней свободы df известно, далее идем классической схемой. С помощью  `scipy.stats.t.ppf(q, df)` вычисляем критические значения, подставляем их в указанные формулы, получаем доверительный интервал. Потом смотрим, покрывает-ли доверительный интервал значение 0. Если да -  нулевую гипотезу не отклоняем.

Можно при желании использовать фeнкцию `scipy.stats.t.interval(....)` которая сразу дает значения границ доверительного интервала для заданного q и df.

Можно также расчётные значения коэффициентов сравнивать с критическими значениями и по их соотношению по стандартной схеме применять или отклонять нулевую гипотезу.

В общем -  вариантов несколько, можно применять любой, только важно понимать, как вычислять саму статистиук, к которой применять t-критерий.